# Solucionar el error "A target array with shape (24, 196) was passed for an output of shape (None, 24) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, categorical

Tengo el siguiente código para clasificar marcas de vehiculos donde uso ImageDataGenerator, y me sale como error:

> ValueError: A target array with shape (24, 196) was passed for an output of shape (None, 24) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

Sé que tiene que ver que le estoy pasando (24,196) que es mi batch y el numero de clases y el solo ve las 24 que es cuando creo la capa y se crea la inconsistencia, pero cómo puedo solucionar?

```
img_width, img_height = 224,224
train_samples = 8144 #EL NUMERO DE COCHES CON LOS QUE VA A ENTRENAR
test_samples = 8041 #EL NUMERO DE COCHES CON LOS QUE HARÁ EL TEST 
epochs = 10 # CUANDO ENTRENE LA RED DE 12 EN 12 PAQUETES, LA VOLVERÁ A HACER, Y ASI HASTA EL NUMERO QUE SE PONGA.
batch_size = 24 # ENTRENARÁ LA RED EN PAQUETES DE 12 Y VOLVERÁ A COGER 12 Y ENTRENAR Y ASÍ....
n_classes = 196

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)


train_directory = "/content/drive/My Drive/stanford-car-dataset-by-classes-folder/car_data/car_data"
filename_train = "train"

train_data_dir = os.path.join(train_directory,filename_train) 

validation_directory = "/content/drive/My Drive/stanford-car-dataset-by-classes-folder/car_data/car_data"
filename_test = "test"

validation_data_dir = os.path.join(validation_directory,filename_test)



model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(24))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))**


model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["acc"])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255, #ENTRE 255 TODAS PARA NORMALIZARLAS, SE SUELE HACER ASI PARA QUE EL PC TRABAJE MEJOR Y MAS RAPIDO
                               zoom_range= 0.2,
                               rotation_range = 5, #ROTA 5 GRADOS
                               horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255) #ENTRE 255 TODAS PARA NORMALIZARLAS, SE SUELE HACER ASI PARA QUE EL PC TRABAJE MEJOR Y MAS RAPIDO


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
                                                target_size = (img_width,img_height),
                                                batch_size = batch_size,
                                                class_mode="categorical")

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir,
                                                   target_size=(img_width,img_height),
                                                   batch_size = batch_size,
                                                   class_mode="categorical")



model_history_2 = model.fit_generator(
                train_generator,
                epochs=10,
                validation_data=validation_generator,
                steps_per_epoch= 5,
                validation_steps= 2000 // batch_size)
```

"""

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

el problema ahí es que tendría que asignar en la capa de salida la cantidad de clases!
en vez de 24, tendría que ser n_classes, en ese dataset creo que es 196.

Seguro que se te borró sin querer.